# Write files to the Apache HTTPD server installed on AWS EC2 instance using Spring Boot Java

Tags: java, spring, amazon-ec2, file-writing

My Springboot app is installed on one server and I've created a separate server (File Server) for images. Both servers are AWS EC2 instances.

So my goal is to write the image-files onto the File Server and anyone can read or access those files via HTTP protocol.

Apache HTTPD server is installed on the File Server. However, I cannot write the files on the File Server.

I'm getting "IOException/FileSystemException - Network path not found".

I've also installed FtpServer and I can upload/write files there. But then I cannot access the files from the internet using the HTTP protocol.

Code:

```
String path = generateFilePath(attachmentRequest); //--> //X.X.X.X/file-uploads/bfdec95a-d730-46b4-a835-d0f85a9bc0cc.jpg 
File file = new File(path); OK
if(!file.exists())
   file.createNewFile(); //Exception --> FileSystemException: \\\\X.X.X.X\\file-uploads\\80ae9bd7-816e-4544-85d3-fd10679adb7d.jpg: The network path was not found.
Files.write(Paths.get(path), attachmentRequest.getFile().getBytes());
```

Comment: Does the EC2 instance have a publicly accessible IP address?

Comment: Yes. I can access index.html file outside of it as well. Also from Security Groups, it's accessible to all.